# Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=6.9.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies.

Tags: c#, php, mysql, asp.net

I am hosting a asp.net website with mysql as a database using EF
my website works fine on my local machine machine
but when i am hosting my website on server 
it's giving me an error

```
Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=6.9.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

  <add assembly="MySql.Data, Version=6.9.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=C5687FC88969C44D" />
```

on my server i have php  version 5.4.37

is there any way i can solve this issue

Comment: Did you install it? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-installation.html

Comment: what exactly are u using? C# and sql server , php and mysql?

Comment: i am using asp.net with c# and mysql as a database

Comment: @SabaAslam so why is this question tagged with PHP and why did you mention your installed PHP version?

Comment: @Dai.. i just wanted to clearify everything thats why i written php version also.. if u dont need u can ignore that part of my question

Answer (score 0):

If it works in your local and not working in server means there is a chance of environment issue like 32bit/64 bit.

So just check the application pool advanced settings.

Enable 32-Bit applications make it to true and try once.

[image]

cheers,
vijay